# Custom Post type shortcodes

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

I create a custom post type (features) in my theme with Advanced Custom Field. I want to know how i can create a shortcodes of my custom post type. so that i just used a shortcode of that custom post type of any page to display a informations that i added in my custom post type (features).

Answer (score 0):

For shortcode, you can use add_shortcode function of Wordpress theme`s function.php.

```
function shortcode_video_slider()
{
    ?>
<div class="cr-carousel">
    <?php
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'video_slider') ); //Change video_slider with your custom post name.
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                <div>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <div class="pimage">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
                    <div class="cr-slider-content">
                <div class="ptitle">
                    <?php
                    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID() , 'video_slider_tex' );
                    // Loop over each item since it's an array
                    if ( $terms != null ){
                    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
                    ?>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></h2>
                    <?php
                    unset($term); } }?>
                </div>
                <div class="cr-video-link">
                <?php 
                    $cr_video_link = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_link', true );
                    echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . $cr_video_link . '" class="wplightbox" title="WordPress Carousel Plugin" data-width="1024" data-height="576">YouTube Lightbox</a>';
                ?>
                </div>
                <div class="cr-video-cat">
                    <div class="cr-slide-category"><span> For</span> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></div>
                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        <?php endwhile;
        if (  $loop->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
            <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Previous', 'domain' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Next <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'domain' ) ); ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
add_shortcode('custom_video_slider','shortcode_video_slider');
```

Now you can use `[custom_video_slider]` where ever you want to display the posts.

Comment: I used this code at the top of the section of feature.php where i set the custom post type(features) <?php 
 function shortcode_features()
{
    ?> and add this at the end of section :<?php
}
add_shortcode('custom_shortcode_features','shortcode_features');
?>  but it is not working

Comment: Paste this code in your child themes function.php
and replace post_type with your custom post type name.

Comment: I create custom post type through the Advanced custom field ,pls let me know how can i used it in functions.php

Comment: You should mention this in your question, that you have used ACF for the custom post type.

Comment: Sorry i forget to mention this , i want to edit my questions but a canntot found the edit button so i send my next questions to mention it and add code .

Comment: now i mention this in it

Comment: Do you have this any solution how can i solve this

Comment: This is not the correct way to create shortcodes. Your code outputs content instead of returning it! https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/ - `Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce an output of any kind. Shortcode functions should return the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode.`